# What does this mean in arabic? (picture)

Tags: arabic

A friend of mine got an arabic tatoo or something, and I want to surprise her that I know what it means.

Can you please tell me

[image]

Comment: Is his name Rakesh?

Comment: no, its a female

Comment: sorry, edited it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By anu chance, is your friend from morocco or is she related to the country somehow. Cause that's probably written Marakash. Arabic name of Morocco

Comment: The Arabic name of Morocco is _Al-Maghrib_, and _Marrakesh_ is the name of a city in Morocco.